# Visual C++ weird option displaying odd things in code view

Tags: visual-c++

https://i.stack.imgur.com/DtoWv.png
i accidently pushed some keys while i wanted to /* and */ my code and those things appeared (arrows, little "-")
any idea how to get rid of that crap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are just displaying whitespace characters.  Toggle with `Ctrl-R Ctrl-W`.

Comment: Oli is correct.  Just to elaborate.  You are telling the editor to show whitespace characters like, `\t`, <space> and `\n`.  It is similar to the paragraph toggle in office when you want to see formatting characters.